# SpriteKit Scene Editor changes are not applied

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, ios9

I'm developing a game for iOS 9 in Swift, my testing device is a iPhone 6.

In Xcode I edited a `.sks` file with the help of the built in Scene Editor (changed the background color, added new nodes etc.). My problem is that these changes are not applied to my compiled game.

I tried following approaches but were not successful:

- Clean the project before building it
- Run the app on the simulator

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Edit: I discovered that after closing the file through "File->Close" and reopening it the old content appeared again. Can somebody explain me why this was happening? I'm sure I saved the file before and were not editing another file.

Comment: Are you leaving an field you edit?  This is the only time it registers.  Also  Try using CMD + S to save the file

Answer (score -1):

SpriteKit and SceneKit Scene Editors are buggy, works in progress.

You'll find all sorts of quirks from one version to another. Unfortunately this might well be one of them. There's no consistency to these quirks and oddities.

There's also no descriptions of changes made from one version of iOS to another with regards Sprite Kit or Scene Kit, which is causing a great deal of annoyance because it's left to the small community to find the changes through trial and error and the sorts of experience you're having.

A compendium of issues would be helpful, and you'd think someone like Apple would have sufficient resources.

If corporations are people, too, then Apple is a poor communicator with attitude issues and a highly secretive nature.